# Html <a> passing php variables but not loading new page

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink, synchronous

I'm working on a website where the user can update the theme by a link at the top of the page. Disclaimer: Later I'll replace the link with Javascript, but for now I want a safe backup in case the user doesn't support Javascript.

I can get the link to display just fine with my PHP. It comes out to `<a href="?theme=dark">` if it is the light theme and it displays as `<a href="?theme=light">` if the user is using the dark theme.

However, clicking either of these links appears to only update the browser of my address bar, forcing me to refresh the page manually to change the theme. The page doesn't reload when I click the link, and therefore the theme does not change. It's acting like an asynchronous request, but the relevant changes are all PHP embedded in the HTML, so they don't occur until a refresh.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to force the page to reload when I click these links?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

EDIT: Here's the current script:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["theme"]) {
    $theme = $_GET["theme"];
    setcookie("theme", $theme, time()+21*24*60*60);
}
else if (isset($_COOKIE["theme"]))
    $theme = $_COOKIE["theme"];
else {
    $theme = "light";
    setcookie("theme", $theme, time()+21*24*60*60);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!-- head content... -->
</head>
<body id="<?php
    echo $_COOKIE["theme"];
    ?>">

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <a id="switch" href="?theme=<?php
            if ($_COOKIE["theme"]=="light")
                echo "dark";
            else
                echo "light";
        ?>">Lights</span>
    </div>
    <!-- Rest of page content -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above code clicking the links takes me to /index.php?theme=*theme*, but I have to refresh before the changes take hold. There is no new html loaded from the server, so the body id does not change.

Cookie stays intact.

P.S. Like I said I will be making an asynchronous version with Javascript, I just want to first support users that don't have it enabled. Thanks.

Comment: Offhand, I'd suggest either adding a random number parameter as a cache buster (`href="random=42234689084746&theme=light`), and/or adding an actual script into the link, so it's `script.php?theme=dark`, in case the lack of one's munging the cache setup.

Comment: Will need to see some of the script, or at least an overview of how it works. At a guess, I'd say you're processing `$_GET['theme']` in the wrong place

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have a look at this, and post the current script in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
<body id="<?php
echo $_COOKIE["theme"];
?>">
```

to this

```
<body id="<?php
echo $theme;
?>">
```

and this

```
if ($_COOKIE["theme"]=="light")
```

to this

```
if ($theme=="light")
```

Your issue is that when you set a cookie in the current page load, it isn't available until the next page load. hence why refreshing seems to make it work.

Comment: Indeed, this does the trick! I seem to recall trying this earlier, but whatever. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jason no problems. nice name.